# How do I solve this error. Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Dompdf\mb_internal_encoding() in /app/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php:275

Tags: php, heroku

- I have deployed an app to Heroku, everything is working well with the app but when I press the print button it is returning nothing, just a white page no pdf is generated.
- In the localhost, everything is working well and the pdf is being generated.
- From Heroku logs, I am getting this error:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNv4r.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 2):

your issue is with the PHP extensions on your hosting platform. For running this library for printing pdf you have to enable **Enable MBString module** in your cpanel or your hosting.
The original question was answered in the library github issues

[Here's the link to that](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1474)

Happy Coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

[`mb_internal_encoding`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding) is a multibyte string function provided by the [`mbstring` extension](https://www.php.net/mbstring).

[Heroku doesn't enable that extension by default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#available-built-in-extensions), but it is available. You can enable it by [adding it to your `composer.json` dependencies](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions), e.g.

```json
{
    "require": {
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
    }
}
```